# Solr WordDelimiterFilter and the slash character

Tags: solr

I have an interesting problem. I have some data with a code field, which contains some identifiers (mostly) in the following format:  E.123/2012.

I've set up a fieldType for this code field:

```
<fieldType name="text_split" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If I search for the exact code ("E.123/2012."), I will get the expected result. If I search for "123 2012", I also get the expected results. If I search for the "123/2012" string, the result set is empty. Tried it with catenateNumbers and catenateWords enabled, with the same results. What I am missing here?

The interesting thing here is that using the field analysis tool, the 123/2012 gives a match if I select the "highlight matches" option. But the same query yields nothing when I try to use it in the query debug tool in the Solr admin. The query works if I use a wilcard search, but I would like to avoid that.

Ps.: I missed a couple of details. I am using Solr version 3.5 on an Ubuntu Linux. And the error log is empty, no exceptions are logged.